# elasticsearch - fuzziness with bool_prefix type

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have the following query:

```
{
        size: 6,
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query,
            type: 'bool_prefix',
            fields: ['recommendation', 'recommendation._2gram', 'recommendation._3gram'],
          },
        },
        highlight: {
          fields: {
            recommendation: {},
          },
        },
      }
```

I want to add `fuzziness: 1` to this query, but it has issues with the `type: 'bool_prefix'`. I need the `type: 'bool_prefix` to remain there b/c its integral to how the query works, but I'd also like to add some fuzziness to it. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of issue? "The fuzziness does not have an effect on the prefix query constructed from the final term"?

Comment: nah when you add it, it doesn't work - try it

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the official [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-bool-prefix) of `bool_prefix`

> The fuzziness, prefix_length, max_expansions, fuzzy_rewrite, and
> fuzzy_transpositions parameters are supported for the terms that are
> used to construct term queries, but do not have an effect on the
> prefix query constructed from the final term.

Adding a working example with index mapping, data, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "recommendation": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type",
        "max_shingle_size": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "recommendation":"good things"
}
{
    "recommendation":"good"
}
```

**Search Query:**

You can add fuzziness parameter with `bool_prefix`, as shown below

```
  {
  "size": 6,
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "goof q",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "recommendation",
        "recommendation._2gram",
        "recommendation._3gram"
      ],
      "fuzziness": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "recommendation": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65817192",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.1203322,
        "_source": {
          "recommendation": "good things"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "recommendation": [
            "<em>good</em> things"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65817192",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.1583319,
        "_source": {
          "recommendation": "good"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "recommendation": [
            "<em>good</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Brian Guan did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @Brian Guan can you please reply back ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with additional fuzzy query combined with multi_match by bool. In your case it would look like this:

```
{
  "size": 6,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "goof q",
            "type": "bool_prefix",
            "fields": [
              "recommendation",
              "recommendation._2gram",
              "recommendation._3gram"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "nameSearch": {
              "value": "goof q",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "recommendation": {}
    }
  }
}
```